# Square with perpendicular lines drawn, prove that they are equal.

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

ABCD is a square. C' is a point on BA and B' is a point on AD such that BB' and CC' are perpendicular. Show that BB' = CC'

I don't know where to start. Use similarities?

Comment: Angles ABB' and BCC' are equal.

Comment: You can start by drawing the figure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

$\alpha = \alpha ‘$ because they are both complement to $\beta$.

Then, by ASA, $\triangle B’AB \cong \triangle C’BC$.

Result follows.

Comment: How can you prove that the angle at C' is the same as beta?

Comment: @GerardL. We can prove that directly but we don't because 1) As mentioned, $\alpha = \alpha'$; 2) AB = BC; 3) $\angle A = \angle C = 90^0$. Then, the two said triangles are congruent. Consequently, $\angle C' = \beta$ by corresponding measurements.

Comment: Will the down-voter explain why?

Comment: That was before his comment. Changing vote.

Answer (score 1):

I am attaching the solution please go through it. This can be done by using co ordinate geometry that I have shown in my solution.

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the slopes multiplied is -1?

Comment: I don't know it. I obtained it by calculation by the steps given above. If the product of the slopes of two lines is $-1$ then these lines are perpendicular.